# Proof of the error bound of the Barnes interpolation method

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Can someone help me with the proof of the Error bound of the Barnes interpolation method if the equation is given as follows:

D(a,k) = exp(-ak^2)

where a = wave number

This formula is found in the article made by Barnes in 1973

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.